# О корне глагола воплотить

Tags: корень-слова

Интересное слово для разбора. Знаю, что многие скажут, что здесь корень "**воплот**", однако хочу процитировать ответ портала Грамота.ру:

> Однако если иметь в виду, что плоть понимается не только как 'тело
> живых существ', но и как 'материальное воплощение, проявление в
> вещественных образах, формах' (см. словарное толкование), то
> становится понятно, что в слове воплотить выделяется корень -плот-

Вы что думаете?

Comment: Не знал, что у этого слова корень ВОПЛОТ-. Я всегда думал, что корень просто -ПЛОТ-.

Comment: Не заглянув в словарь, я бы тоже выделила корень -плот.